# Setting a random number to time

Tags: python, time

I'm trying to generate a random number to use as seconds and turn that number into hours but I don't know how to take the number I generated and pt it into the converter.

So far I have this:

```
import random
import datetime

print(random.randint(30000, 1000000)) = a
    
 
sec = a
res = datetime.timedelta(seconds =sec)
print(res)
```

What should I do to make this work?

Comment: I think you should make your current code able to run first, it can't run for now because you can't assign function call to something, it should be `variable = value`. Another question is why you need a timedelta object to save the seconds when you can simply convert seconds to hours by dividing 3600?

Answer (score 2):

`print()` is a function, and you are setting it to a variable? That will not work. You have to set the value that you are printing, to a variable:

```py
a = random.randint(30000, 1000000)
```

But because you are setting `sec` to `a`, you just need to set `sec` to the random value:

```py
import random
import datetime

sec = random.randint(30000, 1000000)
```

And you don't need the datetime module to convert seconds into hours. You can just divide the number of seconds by 3600(the number of seconds in an hour):

```py
import random

sec = random.randint(30000, 1000000)
hour = sec/3600

print(f"{sec} seconds is equals to {hour} hour(s)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure the spacing is right, I assume your code looks something like this

```
import random
import datetime
print(random.randint(30000, 1000000)) = a
sec = a
res = datetime.timedelta(seconds=sec)
print(res)
```

First of all, if you are assigning the random integer to 'a', you must put 'a' on the left of the equals sign (remember that the value on the right gets assigned to whatever variable is on the left. And if you want to print a's value (the random integer's value) you would have to do it in a separate line.
So your code should look something like this.

```
import random
import datetime
a = random.randint(30000, 1000000)
print(a)
sec = a
res = datetime.timedelta(seconds=sec)
print(res)
```

Hoped that helped!

Comment: Do you need to define `sec` to `a` again? You can remove that in your answer. @Arun Jayaraman

Answer (score 0):

I fix a little in your code.is that what you want?

```py
import random
import datetime

a = random.randint(30000, 1000000)
print(a)
    
 
sec = a
res = datetime.timedelta(seconds =sec)
print(res)
```

Comment: Can you explain what the code is even doing? You are spoonfeeding and not explaining your solution.

Comment: @OldWizard007 sorry for that.the question asked is not clear.so I was expecting dd1eg0 give me feedback then I could know more about the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a random number of seconds converted into days, hours, min and sec, then try this:

```py
import random
import datetime

seconds = (random.randint(30000, 1000000))
res = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds))
print(res)
```

If you wanted just hours, you can use the following code to generate a random seconds value:

```py
import random
import datetime

seconds = (random.randint(30000, 1000000))
hours = round(seconds/3600)

print(f"Time in hours: {hours}")
```

If you don't want the hours rounded to an `int`, just remove the `round()`.

Comment: `str()` is not need to print the string representation for the timedelta object, instead it convert the timedelta to a string which makes further time operation not possible.